# Is Linear Binary Search an over optimization of standard Binary Search

Tags: c++, search, binary

In understanding that Binary Search only works if the List you are searching is sorted, the assumption is that you maintain a sorted list if you are going to Search many times in an application. Searching linearly, 0(n), will always be faster than sorting and then searching, 0(nlog(n)) + log(n).

However, in my research I found that, for small datasets, a linear search, 0(n) is faster than a logarithmic search 0(log(n)). It's recommended in a book I am reading that when searching a dataset with less than 20 items a linear search performs better than a binary search due to overhead in the binary implementation. (Programming and Problem Solving with C++ 6th Edition)

A noticeable optimization to Merge Sort and Quick Sort implements a cutoff value which switches to Insertion sort when the list size becomes small enough... 15 or so items.

Could something similar be done to Binary Search... Is there a noticeable difference in performance if you were to implement a cutoff to a linear search when the size of the list becomes small enough... 20 or so items...

Binary Search Implementation:

```
int BinarySearch(std::vector<int>& values, const int key) {
    int iLo = 0; int iHi = values.size() - 1;
    int iMid = (iHi + iLo) / 2;

    while(iLo <= iHi) {
        if (key < values[iMid])
            iHi = iMid - 1;
        else if (key > values[iMid])
            iLo = iMid + 1;
        else
            return iMid;

        iMid = (iHi + iLo) / 2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Binary Search with Linear Cutoff:

```
int LinearBinarySearch(std::vector<int>& values, const int key) {
    int iLo = 0; int iHi = values.size() - 1;
    int iMid = (iHi + iLo) / 2;

    while (iLo <= iHi) {
        if(iMid == key)
            return iMid;

        //Perform Linear Search When List Size is less than Cutoff
        if (iHi - iLo < CUTOFF) {//Linear Search Performs better on List Size < 20 or so...
        for (int i = iLo; i <= iHi; i++) {
            if (values[i] == key)
                return i;
        }
            return -1;
        }

        else if (key < values[iMid])
            iHi = iMid - 1;
        else
            iLo = iMid + 1;

        iMid = (iHi + iLo) / 2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I populated the Sorted List to be Searched:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    values.push_back(i);
}
```

Then timed the Search of 10 million items in the List with both Implementations of Binary Search and took the average runtime of each Implementation...

The result on average was .000001 seconds per search for both Implementations showing that this cutoff only complicated the Binary Search and had no performance benefits...

I would like to note that testing for equality on different data, such as strings, in the Linear Binary Search implementation may make a standard Binary Search faster, as the standard Binary Search does not test for equality. (This is an assumption that I have not tested)

I guess the question still remains... Why implement a Linear Search over a Binary Search on small sorted data sets when Binary Search is not that complicated and is extremely scalable? Can Someone give an example...

Comment: i dont understand the question, once you sorted the whole range there is nothing to gain anymore by not (again?) sorting 10 elements once you narrowed it down to 10 elements

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number --> I'm searching the range for a value... when the range is smaller than the cutoff value - 20 or so - it performs a linear search as opposed to continuing with the binary search - since it is said that linear search is faster than binary for 20 or less items.... I'm trying to prove this claim... however I was unable to prove that linear is noticeably faster and am asking for example data sets where this would be the case... I need to change the Question... Sorry about that...

Comment: ok, I think I am starting to understand. What is `SIZE`? If you make it big enough the fraction of time that is needed for the last elements becomes insignificant.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number SIZE is the amount of push_back operations I will do to the vector - It is the Length of the Vector before I put all the elements in - in this case I tested it a 10 million - once the Divide and Conquer Algorithm changes iLo and iHi to a value that is less than the Cutoff, which I have set to 20 [meaning the range is 19] via the (iHi - iLo) check, I perform a linear search since it is said that in a range less than 20 or so, a linear search performs better...

Comment: if you search in a vector of 10 million then the fact that you switch to a different algorithm for the last 20 elements will have close to 0 impact. You see a difference for small data sets

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the linear switch happens on each search... not just the last 20 elements of the vector.... for each search once the indexes range is less than 20 (iHi - iLo) - it switches to a linear search.... every search ends with a small data set if I understand correctly - at some point the range will be less than 20... then switch to linear search

Comment: you need roughly 23 steps of binary search to find an element and you need roughly 20 steps to get the range down to 20. So only for the last tiny fraction the two algorithms are different.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes Sir... thats why I didnt think that a linear search would be noticeably different - however, it is said that with small datasets it is... if I were to give SIZE = 19, it would just perform a linear search (after the initialization of index variables etc...) making it a linear search - what is the difference between just giving it a small dataset - of vector size 19 or manipulating the indexes until the range is 19 (making the dataset 19...

Comment: try to see the difference with a vector of `SIZE =19` not 10 million

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Binary Linear Search (Linear Search) and Binary Search - with vector size 19 has an average runtime - over 19 searches (searching for each element in vector) of... .000000 seconds on average - at this time, there seems to be no point in concerning yourself with "when to use linear vs binary in a sorted list", use Binary... - unless there is another example... note, the book i'm reading mentioned the performance of small data sets and linear search for a reason - and many people understand this to be true... I just have yet to see a case when you should choose linear

Comment: how do you measure? Don't expect the difference to be in the range of second or milliseconds.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thats a good point - I am using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); - from the perspective of time, the search is so fast that it doesn't matter if you run at .0000009 or .0000005... its one search over and over... no one will ever notice that... it's instantaneous in both cases...

Comment: Unless I missed something in your question, you don’t need to constantly resort the list. Sort it once then maintain it in a sorted state. Also, if you’re really looking to make the search after insert as efficient as possible, you can use the insertion point as one of the bounds to the search, cutting out half the range on average. Also, since we’re discussing hyper optimization here, a lerp search would probably be better (assuming the data is fairly evenly distributed)

Comment: @Taekahn I wasn't resorting the list every time I searched - I was just stating that a sort and then search will always be slower than a linear search - maintaining a sorted list if you are going to search a lot I would assume is recommended because of this - 0(n) insertion method to maintain sorted list - as for using the insertion point as a bound, I wasn't concerning myself with insertion at this point, however I will keep that in mind when I do implement insertion... I haven't come across Lerp Search in my studies yet, I'll take a look at it. Thanks!!

Comment: That's the problem with big-O notation - it only tells you what to expect when n is very large.  When n is small other factors often take over.  `O(n)` is really `a+b*n`, and `O(log n)` is really `c+d*log n`, because the lower order factors a,b,c,d are dropped.  If a or b is a lot smaller than c or d it can make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of Linear Binary Search is not to return the middle index where the value is stored, which is what Binary Search does. The goal is to position the hi and lo indices until they meet the cutoff range where it will finish the searching task Linearly. Understanding that in cases of small data sets, a linear search is faster than a binary search.

The question naturally becomes how small does a data set have to be for linear search to outperform binary search in a sorted list.

Given a list of 15 sorted values - We have a list of 10 million keys - we need to see if each key is in the list of values...

Compare the algorithms:

Linear Binary Search with Cutoff at 4

```
int LinearBinarySearch(const std::vector<int>& values, const int key) {
    int iLo = 0; int iHi = values.size() - 1;
    int iMid = (iHi + iLo) / 2;

    while (iLo <= iHi) {
        //Perform Linear Search When List Size is less than Cutoff
        if (iHi - iLo < CUTOFF) {//Linear Search Performs better on List Size < 20 or so...
            for (int i = iLo; i <= iHi; i++) {
                if (values[i] == key)
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        else if (key < values[iMid])
            iHi = iMid;
        else
            iLo = iMid;

        iMid = (iHi + iLo) / 2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Binary Search:

```
int BinarySearch(const std::vector<int>& values, const int key) {
    int iLo = 0; int iHi = values.size() - 1;
    int iMid = (iHi + iLo) / 2;

    while(iLo <= iHi) {
        if (key < values[iMid])
            iHi = iMid - 1;
        else if (key > values[iMid])
            iLo = iMid + 1;
        else
            return iMid;

        iMid = (iHi + iLo) / 2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Linear Search:

```
int LinearSearch(const std::vector<int>& values, const int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        if (values[i] == key)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Total runtime for each Algorithm to finish task:

***Linear Search:   5.24367 Seconds***

***Binary Search:   2.43401 Seconds***

***Linear Binary Search Cutoff 4:   2.21329 Seconds***

Note: I started the cutoff value at 20 (less than 20 was recommended in a book I am reading) - it was a second slower than binary search... So I changed the cutoff value until the optimal performance increase was found... CUTOFF = 4... ***(iHi - iLo) < 4 do linear search***.

My first inclination as to why the cutoff mentioned in the book I am reading has such a loose upper bound is that computing power and architecture change over time... this may be incorrect, but the fact remains that we must test our cutoffs when implementing them to find the most optimal cutoff value... To be exact, the book states, "small data sets, say less than 20" - which again implies a test for the most optimal value.

Another example of testing for the most optimal cutoff is implementing a Merge or Quick Sort with a Cutoff to Insertion Sort. The cutoff value I found most optimal using Binary Insertion Sort was 15.

Since Linear Binary Search worked well with ranges of size 3 (cutoff 4) I decided to give Linear Search another go with a sorted values list of 3 elements and 10 million key values to search for.

***Linear Search:   2.0799 Seconds***

***Binary Search:   1.95746 Seconds***

***Linear Binary Search with Cutoff 4:   1.87101 Seconds***

It should be noted that I do not understand at this time how caching etc. works... my expectation on a list of 3 sorted values was that the linear algorithm would outperform both Binary and Linear Binary Searching algorithms due to their overhead, however it did not. I will have to take a look at the Assembly, when I get a better grasp of the language... Visual Studio Community 2019 IDE

I would argue, based on these test runs, that Linear Binary Search is a worthy Optimization to Binary Search due to its increased performance and ease of implementation. (Personally, I may forget to shift to the left or right of the middle index when positioning the Hi or Lo indices, but I wont forget how to write a linear searching algorithm... hopefully...)

One Last Test: 10 million values - 100 million keys

***Binary Search:   81.5836 Seconds***

***Linear Binary Search with Cutoff 4:   54.1304 Seconds***

Honestly, unless shown different, I will always implement Linear Binary Search over Binary Search when Searching a sorted list of ***any*** size due to increased performance and ease of implementation.

thanks **@463035818_is_not_a_number** for the help!! I'll leave my last comment to you for humilities sake :) I was wrong... In taking only the average runtime for each search, while excluding the total runtime for all searches, I was losing time... time adds up.